# insert value from specific position in .dat file into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a .dat file that contains a bunch of text information. What I need to do via php is be able to upload the .dat file to the server which I know how to do already. However once it is uploaded to the server I am not sure how in PHP to open the file and get what ever value is at the 180th position in the file.
The files should all be one row although even if its not I still just need the value from the first row 180th position and take that value and insert it into a mysql database table.

I am looking for any tutorial or documentation on how to do this
Thanks all

Comment: Have you seen this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: what is the format of the dat file?  is it mysql or random data that needs to be parsed into a mysql insert statement?

Comment: the .dat file is a single row of just text .